# Upload files to Azure storage blob from SFTP server

Tags: azure-blob-storage, sftp

I have an Azure storage blob and want to upload large csv files from a SFTP server. How can I do that without having to copy the files locally and then uploading to the Azure blob. Is there a way to do this directly using the Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: This does not look like a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use **Azure Logic App** to copy files from SFTP server to Azure Blob Storage.

In the Azure Logic App, we can add these steps:

**Trigger**: When a file is added or updated to SFTP server

**Action**: Uploads a Blob to Azure Storage

[image]

We can also use **Azcopy** tool inside the SFTP server to copy files from SFTP server to Azure Blob Storage

Comment: Could you suggest how the azcopy tool can be used? From the documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy] it does not seem to support transfer from FTP.

Comment: The AzCopy can be installed in the server. Now inside the server, we can use AzCopy to copy files from the server to Azure Blob Storage